# How to hide table reference from formula bar in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a worksheet that is `xlSheetVeryHidden` and protected VBA to prevent the user from accessing the worksheet. Contained in that worksheet is a table with sensitive data. However, I noticed that someone can find the table name and return the tables contents by simply typing in a cell `=` and then the first letter of the table name.

Is there a way I can prevent the table from appearing in the formula bar?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware of you can't.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/toggling-range-name-visibility/a6c2af7f-d9ee-4f63-989a-2233bee8a50d

One other interesting fact is that, if you only had one table and nothing else in the workbook `ThisWorkbook.Names.Count` will be zero. Which means that Table names are not counted as names at all.But if you try adding a new item in names collection using existing table name you'll get an error.

One more thing, you could try using `[TableNameHERE].ListObject.Name = ChrW(&H4FFF)` and be clever about it, considering limitations.